# How to pass variables to FlowRouter 'named routes'?

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I have the following route:

```
FlowRouter.route('/users/:_id/edit', {
    name: 'Users.edit',
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('App_body', { main: 'Users_edit_page' });
    },
});
```

And I can access the appropriate page with the following code:

```
var userId = Meteor.userId();
FlowRouter.go('/users/' + userId + '/edit');
```

How do you pass the userId through to `Users.edit` name, instead of using the URI path.

Incidentally, I read somewhere that FlowRouter doesn't have named routes - is this not a named route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FlowRouter.go('Users.edit', {id: 1});`

See here: https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#api

Comment: Thanks, that helped in that i was able to find a solution. however I couldn't get the .go() function to work with a second param. instead i used this: var path = FlowRouter.path("Users.edit", {_id: userId});FlowRouter.go(path);

Comment: That's strange, since the `go` function calls `path` internally. Anyway, I'm glad it helped. :)